# Install multiport module on iptables

Tags: iptables

I'am trying to install "fail2ban" on [Cubidebian](http://cubian.org/), a Debian port for Cubieboard (A raspberry like board).

The following rule failed due to "-m multiport --dports ssh" options (It works, when i run manually the command without multiple options).

```
$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j fail2ban-ssh"
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

When i make a cat on "/proc/net/ip_tables_matches", i see that multiport module is not loaded:

```
$ cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
u32
time
string
statistic
state
owner
pkttype
mac
limit
helper
connmark
mark
ah
icmp
socket
socket
quota2
policy
length
iprange
ttl
hashlimit
ecn
udplite
udp
tcp
```

The result of iptables -L -n -v command :

```
$ iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 456 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 396 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-apache (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain fail2ban-ssh (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

What can i do to compile or to enable the multiport module?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Could you paste the output of `iptables -L -n -v` into your question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we generally don't consider hobbyist boards (like RPi et al) to be within the scope of server Server Fault.

Comment: Where i should ask my question?

Answer (score 1):

Multiport requires that CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_MULTIPORT be built into the kernel.  I'm not familiar with Cubidebian, but its normally enabled in Debian.